# AngularJS: Can I disable a form control based on a variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have three user roles (Coordinator, Resource, and User). I have several controls in a form that should be disabled/read-only for the User but not disabled for the other roles.

In my scope I have a variable of current_user[0].role with possible values of co, re, us respectively.

I am currently using ng-show and duplicating the control but these forms are getting very long and complex and I KNOW THERE HAS TO BE A BETTER WAY.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
        <label for="">Time on Task</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="TOT" ng-show="current_user[0].role=='co' || current_user[0].role=='re'" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="TOT" disabled="disabled" ng-show="current_user[0].role=='us'" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Someone PLEASE show me a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)?

Comment: OMG! AngularJS is so complex and complete. How can anyone ever learn what it offers. I did not know this existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) attribute:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="TOT" ng-disabled="current_user[0].role=='us'" />
```

This will add the `disabled` attribute when `current_user[0].role=='us'` is matched. For every HTML attribute, there is normally an `ng-*` equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Put a function on your controller to deal with the logic, then call that function using ng-show or ng-disabled.  Then you can unit test that function and you keep your templates less cluttered:

```
$scope.checkUserRole = function(current_user){
    return current_user[0].role=='co' || current_user[0].role=='re';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add properties onto your scope for each of the 3 possible roles:

```
$scope.isCoordinator = current_user[0].role=='co';
$scope.isResource = current_user[0].role=='re';
$scope.isUser = return current_user[0].role=='us';
```

The view then becomes much more readable:

```
<input type="text" ng-show="isCoordinator || isResource " />
```

If the current_user can change within the view you can add a watch on the current_user and update the properties as appropriate.

You could even add those properties to the current_user object.

Comment: I am going to use your clean-up technique because as you said it becomes so much more readable but then I will use ng-disabled as @RGraham suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I see - I thought the question was more to do with simplifying the UI logic. Remember that ng-show and ng-disabled do behave differently; ng-show can hide a control (display:none) and ng-disabled can disable a control (grey it out).